# SEQUENCE AB INITIO

Tags: sequence, etl, ab-initio

I want to create a field "folio" that is a sequence type:

```
seq-1
seq-2
..
seq-n
```

and that each time I execute my work that page starts from the last one before

```
seq-n+1
seq-n+2
..
```

etc. I used "seq- + next_in_sequence()" but I can't get it to continue on the next execution, otherwise it restarts again. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookup file if you really care about making sure that they are all dense and sequential.